# Does the coin multiplier affect money pickups or money drops?

Tags: crypt-of-the-necrodancer

If I have a 2× coin multiplier, does it double the coins dropped by slain monsters or the coins I collect?

Answer (score 4):

The multiplier aplies to the number of coins dropped, when the moster dies.
For example, if you

- have multiplier 1
- kill a green slime (raising the multiplier to 2)
- kill another green slime
- let a beat go, dropping your multiplier back to 1

you'll find that you still get 1 coin from the first drop and 2 coins from the second.

The multiplier has no further effect on the coins, either dropped or found.

Based on practical test, first tested on 0.375 alpha and leater tested on the newest release version, 1.09.

Comment: Retested this on the newest release version. Still works just like this.

Comment: Also, the crown of greed, dropped from a shopkeeper, will double the obtained coins upon pickup.